# Brute forcing a Caesar Cipher in Python

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to figure out an assignment which asks us to write a program to brute force an encrypted Caesar cipher message. I can do this to the point where my program prints all of the possible decrypted messages, but I am stuck on the next part that states:

> For each of the 26 possibly-decrypted messages, our program needs to figure out whether it "looks like English" instead of encrypted gibberish.
>
> Here's how: We'll take each word in the possibly-decrypted message and look it up in a dictionary (a list of English words). If the word is in the dictionary, then it's an English word; if there are a lot of English words in this possibly-decrypted message, it's likely that this message is the correct decrypted plaintext. (If very few words in the message are in the dictionary, then this message isn't the English plaintext.) So we need to count up how many of the words in each possibly-decrypted message we find in the dictionary, saving that total along with the message that produced it.
>
> Once we're done with all 26 possible decryptions, we should expect that the possibly-decrypted message that had the most "hits" in the dictionary is in fact the correctly decrypted plaintext, and that's the message we return.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz'
infile = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')

def Rotate(key: int) -> str:
    rotate = ""
    for l in alphabet:
        if l in alphabet:
             rotate += alphabet[(alphabet.index(l) + key) % (len(alphabet))]
    return rotate

def Caesar_break(sentence:str)-> str:
    """Takes a str encrypted by a caesar cipher and returns the original string
    without using the cipher key"""
    infile = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
    possible = []
    for key in range(25):
        Rotate(key)
        table = str.maketrans(Rotate(key), alphabet)
        possible.append(sentence.translate(table))
```

The end result should be that

```
Caesar_break("I qwxm bqra lwma nwb bitm bw uwnp jmkicam I qidm wbqmz abcoo bw lw")
```

prints

> I hope this does not take to long because I have other stuff to do

Comment: I can't tell if there's a question here.

Comment: basically the code i have returns a list of all of the possible ways the message code be decoded and I need it to be able to distinguish which decoded messages is the right one and only return that>

Comment: We will try to help if you come across a specific problem, but just saying that your code doesn't do enough means that you are asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: I am just asking for a push in the right direction not the entire code

Comment: You could compare the output to a dictionary of common words.

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be the following:

1. Get an English dictionary and import it to your code.
2. Store all 26 output strings in a list.
3. for each output: count how many of the words exist in the dictionary.
4. Your desired decryption is the output with the highest score.